# Will this the E3400 CPU run on a GA-945P-S3 motherboard?

Tags: cpu

Will this CPU:
[E3400](http://ark.intel.com/products/42772/Intel-Celeron-Processor-E3400-1M-Cache-2_60-GHz-800-MHz-FSB)
,run on my [GA-945P-S3](http://www.gigabyte.com.ro/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2475#sp) 
motherboard ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at the cpu support list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought this particular LGA 775-socket processor would be supported, but it does not appear to be on the list. You may want to contact Gigabyte support for verification.

See CPU Support List: http://www.gigabyte.com.ro/support-downloads/cpu-support-popup.aspx?pid=2475